# Padding in Xaml and Pivot table

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I need put some distance between the word description and the actual description content but no matter what i do here its not working with margins

```
 <Page.Transitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <NavigationThemeTransition>
                <ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo/>
            </NavigationThemeTransition>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Page.Transitions>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

        <Pivot x:Name="myPivot">
            <PivotItem x:Name="pvtMoveDetails" Header="movie details" Margin="28,0,10,22.5" >
                <StackPanel >

                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition  />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image x:Name="moveImage"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Source="{Binding image}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="186"    Width="112"/>


                        <TextBlock FontSize="13" x:Name="txtTtile" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212" Foreground="White" Height="29"  Text="txttitle"/>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Description" Padding="0,0,0,20" ></TextBlock>
                        <ScrollViewer  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="345" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="scrollViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="420" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

                            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" FontSize="13" x:Name="txtPlot" Text="{Binding Description}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="371" Foreground="White" Height="335"   />

                        </ScrollViewer>

                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </PivotItem>


            <PivotItem x:Name="pvtShowTimes" Header="showtimes">


                <ListView x:Name="listViewShowtimes" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Loaded="listViewShowtimes_Loaded">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate>

                            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition  />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock FontSize="13"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="txtshowtime"  Text="{Binding theater_name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212" Foreground="White" Height="29" />
                                <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FormattedShowTimes}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>


                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  Padding="0,0,10,0"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>

                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>

            </PivotItem>
            <!-- Add more pivot items if your View calls for it -->
        </Pivot>

    </Grid>

</Page>
```

You can see here it is showing courrputed right on top of each other :-( and also my scrollviewer is not working correct and scollring the textblock some reason.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the following XAML for your first `PivotItem`, you need to set `Grid.Row="1"` for your description `TextBlock`:

```
      <PivotItem
            x:Name="pvtMoveDetails"
            Margin="28,0,10,22.5"
            Header="movie details">
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image
                    x:Name="moveImage"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Width="112"
                    Height="186"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Source="{Binding image}" />

                <TextBlock
                    x:Name="txtTtile"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Height="29"
                    Margin="16,0,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    FontSize="13"
                    Foreground="White"
                    Text="txttitle"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" />

                <TextBlock
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    Padding="0,16"
                    Text="Description">
                </TextBlock>

                <ScrollViewer
                    Name="scrollViewer1"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    Margin="0,0,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="txtPlot"
                        Width="371"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        FontSize="13"
                        Foreground="White"
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
                        Text="{Binding Description}"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" />

                </ScrollViewer>

            </Grid>
        </PivotItem>
```

Comment: worked a treat just one thing though my title and image poster are not alligned any ideas why mate ?

Comment: kercahi budy grid and row so much hader to figure than margines lol

Comment: have i got the grid and rows right for bigger screens then now at least think got my head around it